# How do i estimate an equation of best fit of a sort-of exponential equation given it's points?

Tags: data-analysis

There is an unnessarly long table of values of an item in a game that grants experience to a player based on one's level in the chosen skill. I think it would be much more appropriate to cite the equation of the relationship between exp and level, but i don't know how. It does not appear to be exponential, but it has a similar characteristic of starting low and raising over time. The table of values can be found [here](http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Small_lamp). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a difficult problem in general, because in general it is so broad. If you suspect the relationship is linear, you can use [least-squares](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Least-squares) to approximate it with a linear relationship and see how well the approximation fits.  If you suspect that the relationship is exponential, you can take the logarithm of all the values, and then use least-squares to find a linear relationship for the logarithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an exponential fit I did by hand using trial and error:

[image]

So it seems the data is more closely described by an exponential than you thought. There are three significant deviations. The value $3770$ at $76$ seems to be a typo; the two values around $50$ may be wrong or adjusted by hand; and it seems that the initial values up to around $15$ were adjusted by hand. So you may want to remove those values and do a standard exponential fit to the rest of the data.

Comment: wow thanks, i guess i should have looked at more points, since there seems to be slight deviation in the data